# Wopi Online Office There is No Save As Button

Tags: office365, powerpoint, ms-office, ms-wopi

We are using Online Office Server 2019 product. Although there is a **Save As** button in Word and Excel but there is no save as button in PowerPoint. The value of `UserCanNotWriteRelative` is set to `false` according to Microsoft's official documentation ([CheckFileInfo Response](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_protocols/ms-wopi/71e66fb4-144b-4369-b597-f425f0b700b9) and [Customizing Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/cloud-storage-partner-program/online/scenarios/customization)). It works for Excel and Word but there is no difference for PowerPoint. How can we activate "Save As" feature on PowerPoint? Any idea what might be causing this or even better, how to fix it? Thanks! Here it's our `CheckFileInfo` response and screenshots;

```
"SupportsExtendedLockLength":false,
"SupportsFileCreation":true,
"SupportsFolders":false,
"SupportsGetLock":true,
"SupportsLocks":true,
"SupportsRename":false,
"SupportsScenarioLinks":false,
"SupportsSecureStore":false,
"SupportsUpdate":true,
"SupportsUserInfo":true,
"LicensesCheckForEditIsEnabled":true,
"ReadOnly":false,
"RestrictedWebViewOnly":false,
"UserCanAttend":false,
"UserCanNotWriteRelative":false,
"UserCanPresent":false,
"UserCanRename":false,"
"UserCanWrite":true,
"WebEditingDisabled":false,
"EditingCannotSave": false
```

[image: PowerPoint Screenshot]

[image: Excel Screenshot]

[image: Word Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/cloud-storage-partner-program/online/scenarios/customization#downloadurl):

> If a `DownloadUrl` isn't provided, Office for the web hides all UI to download the file.
>
> If provided, Word and PowerPoint for the web display UI to download the file. When a user attempts to download the file, Word and PowerPoint ensure that the latest document content is saved back to the WOPI host before navigating the user to the `DownloadUrl` for downloading the file.

Here's the docs for [`CheckFileInfo.DowloadUrl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/cloud-storage-partner-program/rest/files/checkfileinfo/checkfileinfo-response#downloadurl)

Comment: Thanks for your response. We've solved the problem exactly like this. For Excel and Word, providing `UserCanNotWriteRelative` property is enough. This is how the "Save As" feature can be activated in Excel and Word. But for PowerPoint, `UserCanNotWriteRelative` property and a valid `DownloadUrl` property must be presented.

Comment: perfect! thanks for sharing more details!