# Can disable "Save as" feature when integrate with Microsoft 365 for mobile using wopi

Tags: ms-office, ms-wopi

We intend to integrate with Microsoft 365 for mobile.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/cloud-storage-partner-program/mobile/overview

But our app don't allow saving outside of our app.

So can disable "Save as" feature of office app to prevent user save file to other location (local or other cloud service)?

Answer (score 0):

The combination of not providing [`DownloadUrl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/cloud-storage-partner-program/rest/files/checkfileinfo/checkfileinfo-response#downloadurl) and possibly disabling the [`UserCanNotWriteRelative`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/cloud-storage-partner-program/rest/files/checkfileinfo/checkfileinfo-response#usercannotwriterelative) property should do the trick.

Check out my other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75049886/1332034).

Comment: It work "Office for the web" but I don't know it works on mobile or not. Have you integrated with Microsoft 365 for mobile?

Comment: i have no experience with that